# Tableau Calculation between two data sources with no link to each other

Tags: tableau-api

I have a calculation for Rate chart that goes like this:

Total Number of entries (in a given month)/Cumulative number of records each month

But, both these fields are in two separate tables/data sources without any connection/primary key/link at all.

How do I achieve this calculation without joining these two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is **no** link between the tables then there is no way (in Tableau or any other tool) to do what you want.

However, I suspect that what you mean is slightly different: i'm assuming you mean that there is no well-defined database key that links the fields but there are other things in the tables that are common. Like, for example, the date.

If both table contain a date, then Tableau can use that as a way to blend the two datasources together. You might have to make sure that both tables contain dates in a format that Tableau can interpret. Once you do then you can attach both sources to Tableau and then use the date fields as a way to join the tables together (using the Data: Edit Relationships... menu).

Comment: Thanks Matt! there is a date field that is common but again, if joined with Month, it will duplicate values way too much. I am thinking to bring in a common field that could help with linking.

Comment: @TableauBeginner If you are using aggregates from both tables over a time period (eg total entries or total sales) then the duplication won't matter. Tableau can calculate the correct total over the time period in each table separately and then use the totals in any further calculation.

Comment: I am using sum of one of the fields, but because I have joined based on date and one other field(not a primary key) the results are getting duplicated and Tableau including duplicate values why doing summation of that field. I have listed whole problem in other post link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070134/tableau-multiple-charts-with-calculated-field