# Tableau multiple charts with calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

I have below raw data table

**Table Name: A**
`Mode   Country      Month    Visitor
Air     Switzerland  Sep-16   Rob
Air     Switzerland  Oct-16   Bob
Air     Switzerland  Nov-16   Ben
Air     Rome         Sep-16   Zen
Air     Rome         Sep-16   Jen
Air     Rome         Oct-16   Todd
Air     Rome         Nov-16   Ron
Air     Italy        Sep-16   John
Air     Italy        Sep-16   Scott
Air     Italy        Sep-16   Jeff
Air     Italy        Oct-16   Audrey
Air     Italy        Nov-16   Steve
Ground  Switzerland  Sep-16   Rob
Ground  Switzerland  Oct-16   Russel
Ground  Switzerland  Oct-16   Zen
Ground  Rome         Nov-16   Ron
Ground  Italy        Sep-16   Dan
Ground  Italy        Oct-16   Timmy
Ground  Italy        Oct-16   Auidrey
Water   Switzerland  Sep-16   Peter
Water   Switzerland  Sep-16   Josh
Water   Switzerland  Nov-16   Rob
Water   Rome         Oct-16   Ben
Water   Rome         Nov-16   Stuart
Water   Rome         Nov-16   Jen
Water   Rome         Nov-16   Todd
Water   Italy        Sep-16   Scott
Water   Italy        Sep-16   Jeff
Water   Italy        Sep-16   LOLO
Water   Italy        Sep-16   Dabbu
Water   Italy        Nov-16   Danu
Water   Italy        Oct-16   Randy
Water   Italy        Oct-16   Demi`

**Table Name: B**
`Mode    Month    TotalVisitorCount
Air      Sep-16      2500
Ground   Sep-16      30
Water    Sep-16      100
Air      Oct-16      1200
Ground   Oct-16      10
Water    Oct-16      3500
Air      Nov-16      5000
Ground   Nov-16      600
Water    Nov-16      800`

After inner joining these two tables on Mode and Month I want to achieve "Final Table" (below) for Nov-16.

1. How do I have multiple measures/dimension on secondary vertical axis?
2. How do I calculate "VisitorRate", because "DIV(countd[Visitors]/[Total Visitor Count])" formula says, I need aggregation on both sides.

**Final Table**
`Mode/Country  Switzerland    Rome    Italy     VisitorRate     Goal
Air              3            4        5      (3+4+5)/5000      0.06
Ground           3            2        3      (3+2+3)/600       0.06
Water            3            4        7      (3+4+7)/800       0.06`

So basically, I am trying to plot above "Final Table" from   "TableA" and "TableB".
Need below sample chart.

[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How the values in DesiredB table are calculated? I do not see any relation to Table Name A.

Comment: "DesiredTableB" is the sum(monthly visitor count) according to mode. The common fields between these two tables is "Month" and "Country". I want "sum of visitors" divide by "sum of monthly visitor count"

Comment: I don get it . In DesiredB for Nov-16,Air and Rome   you have value  20. How it is calculated?  Table B, had value 2 for Nov-16,Air,Rome. Is there some formula or just the values are random ?

Comment: @arturro : These are random numbers. But what I am trying to get at is "Final Table" using above two raw data tables. "DesiredA" and "DesiredB" is my way of thinking to get to "Final Table". Sorry for the consuing post. I will update it.

Comment: I don't see why we need table A? I have got it 80% there by plugging table B into tableau, pulling [Mode] into my columns shelf and SUM[Montlhy Visitor Count] into my Rows shelf and then pull countries into the the "color" marks card. 
This will give you the overall totals per mode. You can then pull the [Month] into the filter card and filter for whichever month you want.To use the overall total per mode you can use a calculated field and use a LOD function. Here it is, "{FIXED [Mode]:SUM([Monthly Visitor Count])}". That's as far as I got, hope this helps some what

Comment: @lampbob : I have updated the question. "TableB" is updated for just mode and country and month. I can join these two tables and based on that want to calculate "Visitor Rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get Visitor Rate = COUNTD(Visitor Name)/Sum(TotalVisitorCount)

For plotting multiple dimensions on secondary vertical axis, Just used 
Measure Values on the Row section.

How do I have multiple measures/dimension on secondary vertical axis? --Simple "A/B"

How do I calculate "VisitorRate", because "DIV(countd[Visitors]/[Total Visitor Count])" formula says, I need aggregation on both sides. -- Use Measure Values in row part.